# EXCEL Power Pivot Derive hour of day and Week Number

Tags: excel, powerpivot

Building SQL (see below) in power pivot and can't derive hour of the day and week number.  for Hour I tried the HOUR function but the editor kicks it back with'Hour not recognized ans built in function". DatePart("h", [TimeofTransaction]) fails as well.  Format has problems because date need to be a string, I believe. All the same is true for Week Number. Here is the SQL that works so far:

```
SELECT
  Master_Accounts.Account_Type_2
 ,Transaction_Table.Transaction_Type
 ,Transaction_Table.Description
 ,Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction
 ,Transaction_Table.Time_of_Transaction
 ,Transaction_Table.Location_Id
 ,Transaction_Table.Extension
 ,Transaction_Table.Sku
 ,Transaction_Table.ArAmt
 ,Transaction_Table.Balls
 ,Year=DatePart("yyyy",Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction)
 ,MonthNo=Month(Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction)
 ,MonthName=Month(Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction)
 ,Quarter=DATEPART("q", Transaction_Table.Time_of_Transaction)
 ,DayofMonthNo=(Transaction_Table.Date_of_Transaction)
 ,Hour=HOUR(Transaction_Table.Time_of_Transaction)


FROM
  Master_Accounts
  INNER JOIN Transaction_Table
  ON Master_Accounts.Master_ID = Transaction_Table.Account_Number
```

Thanks

Comment: where is the data source?  Within Excel?  Or a SQL Server? etc... Also could you give a sample of your data?  What do these datetime's look like that you're trying to convert (are you sure they are stored properly?) In PowerQuery/DAX the [Hour function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/hour-function-dax) should work if the syntax is correct.  Same with the [WEEKNUM function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/dax/weeknum-function-dax).

Comment: All the data originates in SQL Server.  The functions I am using are in  a SQL statement that originates in the SQL builder in Power Pivot. The DateTime field is DateTime, not text.  Examp: HourofDay=HOUR(DateTimeField)  and is rejected saying that HOUR is not a recognized function.  Same is true for WeekNum. How Hour is entered is in example above. I have been using those fields with no problems in ACCESS for several years. They are stored correctly.